# How can I adapt ANOVA for binary data?

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, generalized-linear-model

I have four competing models which I use to predict a binary outcome variable (say, employment status after graduating, 1 = employed, 0 = not-employed) for n subjects. A natural metric of model performance is hit rate which is the percentage of correct predictions for each one of the models.

It seems to me that I cannot use ANOVA in this setting as the data violates the assumptions underlying ANOVA. Is there an equivalent procedure I could use instead of ANOVA in the above setting to test for the hypothesis that all four models are equally effective?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contingency table (chi-square). Also Logistic Regression is your friend - use dummy variables.