# ANOVA for binomially-distributed data

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, generalized-linear-model

Is ANOVA valid for binomial data?

I have 7 binomial groups and I want to test whether the distributions of all of the groups are equal or whether the distribution of the first group is significantly different than the distribution of groups 2-7.

What tests would accomplish this? I was thinking of just combining groups 2-7 and then performing a chi-square test on group 1 vs groups 2-7. Is this valid?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a "binomial group"?  Is it a group of individuals where each has an independent observation from a Binomial(n,p) distribution with n known and p unknown?  Could the observations be Bernoulli (0/1) variates, so that the sum in each group is binomial?  Something else?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean - each group is composed of Bernoulli (0,1) variates and when summed up they constitute a binomial r.v.

Comment: @whuber, Can you please rename tag "glm" into "generalized linear model". Because there is confusion among statisticians and site visitors over GLM abbreviation. Some people take it as "generalized..." and some for "general...". For "general linear model" we have a good tag "linear model" already.

Comment: @ttnphns Excellent point.  Indeed, a Google search indicates "GLM" is used twice as often for "general linear model" than for "generalized linear model."  I added the [new tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generalized-linear-model), made [glm](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glm) a synonym of it (I can't destroy "glm" entirely), changed its description, and added a clarification to the [multiple-regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-regression) tag wiki.

Comment: Same question as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17/how-can-i-adapt-anova-for-binary-data